# Typescript, CRUD Applications, and the generation of resource identifiers

Tags: rest, typescript, crud

I am currently trying a create a fairly simple, declarative RESTful CRUD framework, whereby I can define a resource type, and have both the API endpoint created, as well as the the functions to Create/Read/Update/Delete the declared resource.

ie. the usage would look a little like this:

```
interface Student {
     name: string; 
     dob: Date; 
}   

const {fetchFunctions, initApp} = createContract<Student>(app, "/students"); 

//Serverside: 
const app = express(); 
initApp(app); 

//Clientside     
fetchFunctions.post({   //OK. 
   name: "bob", 
   dob: "11/11/1911"
}); 

fetchFunctions.post({   //Type error, because dob isn't included. 
    name: "Bob"
});


const student = await fetchFunctions.get("111"); 
console.log(student.name); //OK. 
console.log(student.foo); //Type error, because Student doesn't have foo.
```

Where I'm running into an issue is around the generation of IDs, and whether to include them in the resource object itself.

ie. Say I have done `GET /students`, to get a list of students, then I have to return the ID of the resources *somewhere* otherwise I am going to have no way to update them.

So either, I could put the ID on the resource:

```
[
   {
      id: "123", 
      name: "Bob", 
      dob: "11/11/1911", 
   }, 
   {
      id: "234", 
      name: "Alice", 
      dob: "12/12/1912", 
   }
]
```

Or on some 'Resource Wrappers'

```
[
   {
     id: "123", 
     data: {
       name: "Bob", 
       dob: "11/11/1911", 
     }
   }, 
   {
     id: "234", 
     data: {
       name: "Alice", 
       dob: "12/12/1912", 
     }
   }
]
```

(Is this even RESTful? , and really, it's not even different data).

The problem then, is I have to add the ID to the `Student` interface, and if I want to POST a student (without the ID), then I have to make it optional, and that starts getting messy, (ie. warnings about a possible null id everwhere).

Another solution is that I have two interfaces one `Student` and one `NotYetCreatedStudent` that doesn't have an ID, and I POST the latter instead. This seems kind of tidy in a sense - but I don't really like the ID of having to create two interfaces for every resource, having a whole second generic type on my functions etc.

This [popular Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) addresses the difference between POST and PUT, and basically the consensus seems to be that for creating a new resource, you do either:

```
POST /resource
```

or

```
PUT /resource/123
```

So maybe instead, then I could just not do 'POST without ID to create a resource' and instead do 'generate a UUID on the client side and PUT with ID' - which is seeming like the simplest solution.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about RESTful APIs here that would help me solve this problem?

Comment: just generate the ids client side. youll need them if you manipulate more than one object at a time anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's some clever Typescript that solves this:

```
interface HasId {
    id: string; 
}

type Omit<T extends HasId, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
type OptionalId<T extends HasId> = Omit<T, "id"> | T;
```

And now, when you are creating your function `createContract`, then you create it with the signature

```
function createContract<T extends HasId> {

}
```

And the `post` function will have the signature

```
interface PostFunction<T>{
    (data: OptionalId<T>) :Promise<T>; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Say I have done GET /students, to get a list of students, then I have to return the ID of the resources somewhere otherwise I am going to have no way to update them.

Yes -- welcome to the world of hypermedia.  More precisely, you need to return a link -- which means that your media types must clearly define how links are described in representations.

For example, in HTML we have `a` and `img` and `script` and so on that all have slightly different semantics.

> The problem then, is I have to add the ID to the Student interface, and if I want to POST a student (without the ID), then I have to make it optional, and that starts getting messy, (ie. warnings about a possible null id everywhere).

Yes: it often makes sense for message schema to have optional fields, and that in turn means that the consumer of the message needs to be able to handle the optional-data-absent cases.

That doesn't necessarily mean that you need to go that way.  Perhaps instead of submitting a `Student`, what the client sends is an `EnrollmentRequest`, which includes some of the student information but doesn't include bookkeeping metadata.

> Is there something I'm misunderstanding about RESTful APIs here that would help me solve this problem?

A lot of people misunderstand [REST](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), so it's likely.

Here's my summary: REST is the [architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/software_arch.htm#sec_1_5) of the world wide web.  So if you think through how you would design a web site that does the work, then you will have an understanding of what a RESTful design would be, and you can start thinking about alternative implementations.

Comment: Just read Roy Fielding's dissertation if you want to understand what REST really is.